# Phonegap Config.xml changes do not take affect in iOS app

Tags: ios, cordova

I created an application using phone gap build for iOS, in that Config.xml changes not working in app.For example i changed the below and has no affect.
where i am doing mistake.Have to place config.xml file inside platform/ios.

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
 <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my environment, there **are** two `config.xml` files, i.e., `/path/to/project/www/config.xml` and `/path/to/project/Staging/config.xml`.

Which file did you edit?

Comment: I am having only one config.xml and edited in /path/to/project/www/config.xml.

Comment: Really? `Staging/config.xml` is certainly generated when I run phonegap command. I thought that if you're in the same case, I would help you. I'm sorry.